# Reading a value from the registry C++

Tags: c++, registry

I want to get the path of where an application is installed. In the registry, there is an entry which gives the path of my application, see this screenshot:
http://i56.tinypic.com/2ly1l6s.jpg

I want to read the path where my application is located. In other words, I want the C:\Projects\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe part. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
HKEY hKey;
wchar_t mydata[2048];
DWORD dataLength = sizeof(mydata);
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
LPVOID messagecaliss;
LONG regOpenCriss = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);
GetLastError();
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, GetLastError(), NULL,(LPTSTR) &messagecaliss, 0, NULL );
if (regOpenCriss == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
RegQueryValueEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "TestApplication", 0, &dwType, (BYTE*)mydata, &dataLength);
wprintf(L"%s\n", mydata);
system("PAUSE");
}
else
    MessageBox(NULL,(LPCTSTR)messagecaliss,"ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

This doesn't work, junk characters are printed. Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be useful to specify what compiler / development tool you use.

Comment: I use Visual Studio C++ 2010, windows 7

Comment: What's wrong with the path from argv[]?

Comment: im not looking for the path of the executable, but of another app

Comment: You are moving into dangerous grounds as far as user experience goes. Without explicit user actions your app should not tamper with other applications.

Answer (score 5):

you're using non-UNICODE version o RegQueryValueEx and you're diplaying it with wide-char version of printf. Use either printf or change to wprintf( L"%S" ,mydata )

Note : RegQueryValueEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER ,... ) must be RegQueryValueEx( hKey ,... )

Comment: does the value you query exists ? if so ,check the return value of RegQueryValueEx.

Comment: And check that dwType has been set to [REG_SZ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724884(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I got results after:

1. I surround the strings with _T()
2. I call `RegQueryValueEx` with `hKey` as the first parameter

You should store the result of `RegQueryValueEx` in a variable and check it. Handle the failure case...

Answer (score 1):

> This doesn't work

How do you know that without checking the return value of `RegQueryValueEx`?

> junk characters are printed

No. It's not junk. You didn't ask for a wide character string, so you cannot expect to get one. Compile with Unicode enabled and call `RegQueryValueEx` with `L"TestApplication"` or `_T("TestApplication")` or `TEXT("TestApplication")`. `RegQueryValueEx` is just a typedef for `RegQueryValueExA` or `RegQueryValueExW`, depending on whether Unicode is defined during compile time or not.

> Thank you very much

You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A main problem with the code you present is that you have C style casts. Each cast is a bug attractor. And in fact, some of your casts are bugs (hiding that you're using incompatible character types).

> I want to read the path where my application is located.

Use `GetModuleFileName`.

> [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx):
>   Retrieves the fully-qualified path

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Argh, I hate the hormonal kids. Why didn't God give them minds?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I think the OP is asking for where some "other" application is installed, not the currently running one.  So GetModuleFileName won't help.

Comment: @Guy: Well he does write "my application", not "other application". But quite possibly you're right that he's thinking of something else than he's actually asking. The registry code point in that direction, yes  --  but on the other hand, also points in direction of not knowing about `GetModuleFileName`... ;-)